# How can I run an app that works on IIS 10 in IIS 7 or IIS 8.5?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tested the [default MVC template that visual 2017 provides](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-first-asp.net-mvc-application), and tested it on IIS 10,in my local machine, and works great.

When I test it on Windows server 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5) or in Windows server 2008 (IIS 7) I get a lot of errors and all I can do is see a list of the files in the root directory instead of the rendered website.

What I do to get the webste that IIS 10 is able to run is to  Debug tth aplicationn in visual studio, then I find the path of that app, that IIS express is using, and then copy it to a folder that IIS has access to, in IIS 10 it works great, in IIS 7.0 and in IIS 8.5 and can't get it to work.

[image: listed elements]

Pease help. What can I do?

> Update:

I'm currently installing updates on the w2012r2 system, which includes updates in .net framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally ended up solving this.

I had to allow directory browsing in IIS 7.

Also added in my web.config file the following lines.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

Finally, I had to run the following command: ([explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/2015129/error-message-after-you-install-the-net-framework-4-0-could-not-load-t))

> `aspnet_regiis.exe /iru`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you have to do with your MVC app to make it work with IIS 7 - 10.

You just need to make sure the Server and IIS is configured correctly:

- Make sure the .NET version you require is installed on the server.
- Make sure ASP.NET is installed as part of IIS.
- Make sure the application pool you are using is set to your Framework version.
- You should also turn off Directory browsing on a production server.

There are many resources on the net on how to configure IIS and ASP.NET

> I get a lot of errors

is not very helpful if you want people to help you, you need to list the errors in detail.